# Access value in OpenCV Mat object UINT16

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I access particular cell in Opencv Mat, type **UINT16**
I have tried the ones below, but nothing works.

```
depthV = depthIm.at<int>(i, j);
depthV = depthIm.at<UINT16>(i, j);
depthV = depthIm.at<float>(i, j);
depthV = depthIm.at<double>(i, j);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int depthV = depthIm.at<unsigned short>(i, j);
```